# Prevent a scrollviewer from refocusing to the left after expanding a child in a treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview, scrollviewer

I have a customized TreeView inside a ScrollViewer (I needed to overwrite the template for this application).

The treeviewitems have two columns. One for the togglebutton and the other for the content. The toggle button column width has been set to 0 to hide the toggle button and align all the elements. The items data template contains a canvas that draws a rectangle for each item, which can be quite long in the horizontal, and has a left offset from the canvas.

It all draws correctly but when you double click a rectangle to expand the child, the scrollviewer refocuses the treeview to the left. I assume it is refocusing because it realigns to the toggle button or the left of the item content.

Does anyone have any ideas how to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the suggestion I received from a colleague was to catch the event.

I tried a few different events and found the one that bubbled up to the ScrollViewer.

I caught the MouseDown event on the rectangle, marked it as handled and traversed up the `event.Source.Parent` until I got to the control to expand the child.

Hope this helps others.

```
private void GanttBarMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var theVm = ((GanttItemViewModel) ((ContentPresenter) ((FrameworkElement) ((FrameworkElement) e.Source).Parent).TemplatedParent).Content);
        if (e.ClickCount == 1)
        {
            theVm.IsSelected = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            theVm.IsSelected = true;
            theVm.IsExpanded = theVm.IsExpanded ? false : true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```